# Ways to post query data to URL without a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass a couple bits of info through the URL just by clicking a link, rather than by using action="GET" with a form and input button. Is this possible? This is *client-side only*, there is no server, so suggestions regarding PHP etc. will not be useful in this circumstance.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?  You're gonna need to use JavScript to create a URL, and then load it.

Comment: Can you show an example? The data is already in the page, for all practical concerns. It was passed in from elsewhere. Now it needs to be sent through this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna need to use JavaScript to get all the values, and then combine them into a URL.

Here's an example (using the [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) library):

```
<a href="http://example.com/test.html" id="paramLink">Click</a>

<script>
$(function(){
  // The data, from the page
  var id = 1, name = 'test';

  // Add event to link
  $('#paramLink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop the browser from following the link

    location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?id='+id+'&name='+name; // Build the URL
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

In your anchor, change the href to include a querystring at the end.

e.g.

```
 <a href="http://www.example.com/test.html?parameter=2">
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have access to the variables on the client, you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    navigateToPage = function(val){        
        window.location.href = "/somefolder/somefile.htm?id=" + val;
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Navigate" onclick="navigateToPage(5);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

put your bit of info in anchor and post along with it

```
<a href="yourpage.php?id=2&action=edit"> click! </a>
```

how to get these values on redirected page; and in case you using PHP.

```
$id=intval($_REQUEST['id']);
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
```